# Should I mention I will be having my birthday on the day of the interview?

Tags: interviewing, behavior

I will be having an extremely important interview with a company I am very interested in. After doing some research I am anticipating some off-topic conversations with their team leads and managers. Coincidentally, I will be having my birthday party on the same day and I will be in a big rush for getting certain accommodations and preparations done for the evening. As I am pretty open minded it is possible I could have mentioned it as part of the conversation. However, I know that this interview might be the final one and I would hate to input any bias or create any uneasiness during the process from either side. So, if it comes to small talk and my plans, should I even mention I will be preparing for my birthday party tonight or should I just keep it to myself?

Comment: No, don't mention it.

Comment: @WorkerDrone any specific reason?

Comment: In Germany, they would know because the birthday is part of the CV. If they are attentive and actually read your documents, they might congratulate you, maybe even ask if there is a party planned if they want to chat off-topic. Of course internationally the date of birth is usually off-limits.

Answer (score 16):

Happy birthday!

I don't know that I would mention `preparing` or `a big rush` for the party. You want them to think you're focused on the interview, not a party.

---

I wouldn't necessarily avoid the fact that it's your birthday nor would I go out of the way to mention it.

I interviewed for a company on my 22nd birthday. They took me out to lunch and it came up. They got me a piece of cake and had the waitstaff sing to me (how embarrassing!). It showed me a lot about the company culture and the personalities of the people I'd be working with. I was a good sport, and that told them something too.

I also received and signed an offer that day. That was a pretty good birthday.

---

Final interviews are often formalities that are more about assessing personality and cultural fit. Particularly if they pull the conversation off-topic. At that point mentioning your birthday and impending party isn't a bad thing. Just be really positive.

> Today is a really good day. I have an interview with a great company, and I get to celebrate my birthday. What more could I ask for?

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, I agree. I guess it's better to be fully open and honest than try to come up with a story last minute and look awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Happy Birthday!

I think that it's perfectly fine for you to mention, at the *start* of the day, that you have plans for the evening.  They can and will adjust their interview schedule accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

Imagine if EVERY applicant that day came through wanting to talk about stuff that really doesn't pertain to the job.  How much time would the interview team actually have to accommodate all applicants?

You're lucky to get the interview.  Don't put the team in a position where they feel you're someone likely to not consider their time.  It can create an awkward "flag" that people will disqualify you with.

Comment: Well, myself, I wouldn't ever bring this up first. What I see happening is them trying to have an off-topic conversation with me and so I will have an option of telling them the truth of what I am really up to tonight or simply not mentioning that I have my birthday on this day.

Comment: You are really overthinking this.  In the remote possibility that this actually gets asked (and it's quite remote) just say, "I'm spending time with friends."  Don't volunteer information that you're not asked.

Comment: Yeah, but don't be too terrified of "what 'might' happen," either.  Just tell 'em that you need to be finished by a certain time. If they ask, tell 'em it's your birthday. Hey, "we interviewers" have birthdays, too!  The various interview stages will be given a schedule that they'll need to stick to. *(But, they don't.)* If they know **early** that morning, they can tweak things.